# lambda+for_each+delete on STL containers

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stl, delete-operator

I'm trying to get a simple delete every pointer in my vector/list/... function written with an ultra cool lambda function.

```
template <typename T>
void delete_clear(T const& cont)
{
    for_each(T.begin(), T.end(), [](???){ ???->delete() } );
}
```

I have no clue what to fill in for the ???'s. Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: This is what it should look like:

```
template <typename Container>
void delete_clear(Container &c)
{
    for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [](typename Container::value_type x){ delete x; } );
    c.clear();
}
```

Comment: You'll need to make `cont` non-const in order to call `clear()` on it. And call it on `cont`, not T ;-p

Comment: If you need pointer containers, have a look at the Boost Pointer Container library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

Comment: Don't take a container by reference. Use iterators.

Comment: Just curious. Can you use "auto x", like [](auto x){ delete x; } ? It would be cool if you could.

Comment: No but you could use `decltype(*c.begin()) x`

Comment: Any reason for not using `unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two issues here: the lambda syntax itself, and how to get the value type of a container:

To call the `mydelete()` function on each pointer (assuming you've defined a `mydelete()` member function):

```
for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [](typename T::value_type x){ x->mydelete(); } );
```

To delete them using the delete operator:

```
for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [](typename T::value_type x){ delete x; } );
```

Also, lambda isn't necessarily the coolest new feature in C++11 for a given problem:

```
for(auto x : c) { delete x; }
```

I'd note that it's a bit dodgy to take a *const* reference to a container, and delete everything in it, although the language doesn't stop you because of what pointers are. Are you sure that's a "constant" operation, though, within the meaning and use of your container?

If you're writing this code, maybe you'd benefit from [Boost pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), or containers of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Two good answers, but this one I like better (operator<->member function delete + one line). Thanks

Comment: Except that delete is a keyword and thus can't be the name of anything.

Comment: Looks like this (and the question update) mixes type T with a value of type T.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like:

```
template <typename Container>
void delete_all(const Container& c)
{
    typedef typename Container::value_type Value;
    std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [](const Value& v){ delete v; });
}
```

Note that this doesn't *remove* the pointers from the container, so you need to be very careful what you do with the container and the pointers it contains after you call this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested specifically in lambdas?

If you're using boost you can write:

```
for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), boost::checked_delete<Container::value_type>);
```